# CANNOT copying char into last address of char* ( string )?

Tags: c, string, memory, stack-based

i would like to copy data of `char*` to another last address of `char*`

**illustration**

```
var1 -> O
var2 -> K
```

**first step**

```
var1 -> OK
var2 -> K
```

copy `var2` to `var1`

**result**

`var1 -> OK`

**written code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void timpah(char *dest, char *src, int l_dest, int l_src)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < l_dest)
    {
        dest[l_dest+i] = src[l_src+i];
    i++;
    }
}

int main()
{

char res[2024];
res[1] = 0x4f;

char a[] = {0x4b};


timpah(res,a,1,1);

printf("%s [%d]\n",res,strlen(res));
return 0;
}
```

**run**

```
root@xxx:/tmp# gcc -o a a.c
root@xxx:/tmp# ./a
 [0]
```

**question**

why my code is not working ? or is there any function had exists already to perform these, but i haven't know it yet ?

thx for any attention

Comment: What happens if you print res just after `res[1] = 0x4f;` ? What is in `res[0]`?

Comment: im quite sure its like typos, but when im correcting `res[1] = 0x4f` to `res[0] = 0x4f` and `timpah(res,a,1,1)` to `timpah(res,a,1,2)`, the result still the same.. any solution ?

Comment: What are l_dest and l_src? Are they supposed to be lengths or offsets?

Comment: Then why do you use them as offsets in `dest[l_dest+i] = src[l_src+i];` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't setting `res[0]` at any point. If `res[0]` contains `\0` your string ends there. You are probably making things harder than they have to be; you can always use `strncpy` and `strncat`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should have a look at strncat(), strncpy(), etc

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void timpah(char *dest, char *src, int l_dest, int l_src)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < l_dest)
    {
        dest[l_dest+i] = src[l_src+i];
    i++;
    }
}

int main()
{

char res[2024];
res[0] = 0x4f;


char a[] = {0x4b};


timpah(res,a,1,0);

res[2] = '\0';
printf("%s [%d]\n",res,strlen(res));
return 0;
}
```